# setnames in pipeline R code

Tags: r, pipeline, names

I was wondering if it was possible to set the names of elements of a list at the end of a pipeline code.

```
  data <- input_vars %>% 
    purrr::map(get_data)

  names(data) <- input_vars
```

Currently I pass a string of variables into a function which retrieves a list of dataframes. Unfortunately this list does not automatically have named elements, but I add them "manually" afterwards. In order to improve readability I would like to have something as follows

```
  data <- input_vars%>% 
    purrr::map(get_comm_data) %>%
    setnames(input_vars)
```

However, this gives me the following error: *Error in setnames(., input_vars) : x is not a data.table or data.frame*

Does someone have an elegant solution to this?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It would be easier with a reproductible example. Here, `setnames` if a fonction exported from `data.table` package and you seem not to work with `data.table`.
Base R function is `setNames` and should work. You could also use `set_names` from `purrr` package.

Comment: You should read the docs for the functions you're trying to use, not simply guess at the name of the function you need. In this case, try `?setnames`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To set names of an object in a pipeline, use `setNames` or `purrr::set_names`

```r
1:3 %>%
  purrr::map(~ rnorm(5, .x)) %>%
  purrr::set_names(paste0('V', 1:3))
#> $V1
#> [1] 1.4101568 2.0189473 1.0042691 1.4561920 0.8683156
#> 
#> $V2
#> [1] 2.0577889 2.4805984 1.4519552 0.9438844 0.4097615
#> 
#> $V3
#> [1] 0.4065113 4.0044538 2.8644864 2.4632038 4.0581380
```

```r
1:3 %>%
  purrr::map(~ rnorm(5, .x)) %>%
  setNames(paste0('V', 1:3))
#> $V1
#> [1] 0.52503624 0.69096126 0.08765667 0.97904520 0.29317579
#> 
#> $V2
#> [1] 2.561081 1.535689 1.681768 2.739482 1.842833
#> 
#> $V3
#> [1] 2.619798 1.341227 2.897310 2.860252 1.664778
```

With `purrr::map` you could also name your `input_vars` as `map` keep names.

```r
c(V1 = 1, V2 = 2, V3 = 3) %>%
  purrr::map(~ rnorm(5, .x))
#> $V1
#> [1]  1.74474389  1.69347668 -1.03898393  0.09779935  0.95341349
#> 
#> $V2
#> [1] 1.5993430 0.8684279 1.6690726 2.9890697 3.8602331
#> 
#> $V3
#> [1] 3.453653 3.392207 2.734143 1.256568 3.692433
```